# How to scroll to selected node in PrimeNG Tree

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a page with PrimeNG tree and an autocomplete field. My requirement is Tree should be expanded to the matching node when user enters and selects a text in autocomplete field and also it should scroll to the matching node and highlight the node.

I tried to expand the tree by setting  'expanded' property to 'true'. But I am not finding a way to scroll to selected node. Any help on this is appreciated.

Also please let me know if there is any method that expands the tree using selected node.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most beautiful solution, but you can achieve this by using the following util method.

```
 public scrollToSelectionPrimeNgDataTable(table: DataTable, element: HTMLElement) {
    if (table.selection !== null && table.value !== null) {
        let index = table.value.indexOf(table.selection);
        let list = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
        if (list !== null && index < list.length) {
            let targetElement = list.item(index);
            targetElement.scrollIntoView()
        }
    }
}
```

To use this Method you have to pass a reference of the DataTable and the table itself as HTMLElement to the method. You can get both by using Angular2's `@ViewChild` decorator.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on David Asher's answer, this is a simpler working solution for PrimeNG's tree:

HTML:

```
<p-tree #mytreeid id="mytree"></p-tree>
```

Angular:

```
@ViewChild("mytree") mytree: Tree;

// selection is the TreeNode you want to scroll into view
scrollToSelectionPrimeNgDataTree(selection, tree, elementIdName) {
      if (tree.value !== null) {
          let index = tree.value.indexOf(selection);
          document.getElementById(elementIdName).querySelectorAll("p-treenode")[index].scrollIntoView();
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate a bit like where you can call this function any particular hook?

Answer (score 1):

Adding on John's and David's answers.
Following statement returns all nodes in tree (including children) as a flat array of Elements.

```
document.getElementById(elementIdName).querySelectorAll("p-treenode")
```

Therefore, the index of the searched node should be calculated correctly. It depends on whether node is expanded or not. Node tree should be traversed in depth-first (pre-order) manner to find node's index. It can be implemented using recursion:

```
private CalculateIndex(tree: TreeNode[], predicate: (node: TreeNode) => boolean,
  startIndex: number = 0 ): { found: boolean; index: number } 
 {
  let index: number = startIndex;
  let found = false;
  for (const node of tree) {
     found = predicate(node);
     if (found) {
        break;
     }

     index++;
     if (node.expanded) {
        ({ found, index } = this.CalculateIndex(node.children, predicate, index));
        if (found) {
           break;
        }
     }
  }

  return { found, index };
```

}

Found index then can be used in the following function to scroll to the node:

```
private scrollToSelection(selection: TreeNode, treeNodes: TreeNode[], treeElementId: string) {
  const { found, index } = this.CalculateIndex(treeNodes, (node: TreeNode) => node === selection);
  if (found) {
     const treeElement = document.getElementById(treeElementId);
     const allTreeNodes = treeElement.querySelectorAll('p-treenode');
     const node = allTreeNodes[index];
     if (node) {
        node.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'center'});
     }
  }
```

}

Hope it helped a little.

Answer (score 1):

These all have assumptions. John's seems to assume a root item. Vadym's assumes tree is fully expanded.  I use mine as the form is initially loaded.  I expand the selected item to the root array and leave the remaining nested tree elements collapsed.  Additionally, I have populated the parent.  I have created the following static helper method version of John's solution:

```
/*
** Scroll to selected item.
**
** Tree value is obtained via:
**  <p-tree #MyTree [value]='data' name='myTree' selectionMode='single' [(selection)]='selected'></p-tree>
**  @ViewChild( 'MyTree' ) mtree: Tree;
** elementIdName value is in above example: myTree
** Example:
**  _PCOMMON.treeScrollToSelectedItem( mtree, 'myTree' );
*/
public static treeScrollToSelectedItem( tree: Tree, elementIdName: string ): number {
    let idx: number = -1;
    if ( tree.value !== null && tree.selection !== undefined ) {
        idx = 0; // Count levels deep
        let items: TreeNode[] = [];
        let node: TreeNode = tree.selection;
        do {
            if( node.parent !== undefined && node.parent !== null ) {
                items = node.parent.children; // begin of level
                idx++;
            } else {
                items = tree.value;
            }
            idx = items.findIndex( k => k.key === node.key ) + idx;
            node = node.parent;
        }
        while ( node !== undefined && node !== null );
        if( idx > -1 ) {
            document.getElementById( elementIdName ).querySelectorAll( 'p-treenode' )[ idx ].scrollIntoView( );
        }
    }
    return idx;
}
```

This is the testing structure:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeNode, SelectItem } from 'primeng/api';
import { TreeModule, Tree } from 'primeng/tree';
import { _PCOMMON } from './pcommon';
//
@Component({
    template: `<p-tree #MyTree [value]='treeData' id='myTree' name='myTree' selectionMode='single' [(selection)]='selected'></p-tree>`
})
class TestTreeComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild( 'MyTree' ) mtree: Tree;
    treeData: TreeNode[];
    selected: TreeNode = undefined;
    ngOnInit () {
        this.treeData = [
            { label: 'One (1)', key: '1', children: [], parent: undefined, expanded: false },
            { label: 'Two (2)', key: '2', children: [], parent: undefined, expanded: false },
            { label: 'Three (3)', key: '3', children: [], parent: undefined, expanded: true },
            { label: 'Four (4)', key: '4', children: [], parent: undefined, expanded: false }
        ];
        const children: TreeNode[] = [
            { label: 'Five (5)', key: '5', children: [], parent: this.treeData[2], expanded: false },
            { label: 'Six (6)', key: '6', children: [], parent: this.treeData[2], expanded: false },
            { label: 'Seven (7)', key: '7', children: [], parent: this.treeData[2], expanded: true }
        ];
        const children2: TreeNode[] = [
            { label: 'Eight (8)', key: '8', children: [], parent: children[2], expanded: false },
            { label: 'Nine (9)', key: '9', children: [], parent: children[2], expanded: false }
        ];
        this.treeData[2].children = children;
        this.treeData[2].children[2].children = children2;
    }
    //
}
//
import { TestBed, waitForAsync, ComponentFixture, inject, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
//
fdescribe('_PCOMMON_TreeComponent', () => {
    /*
    ** The treeData is as follows:
    ** One (1)
    ** Two (2)
    ** Three (3)
    **   Five (5)
    **   Six (6)
    **   Seven (7)
    **     Eight (8)
    **     Nine (9)
    ** Four (4)
    */
    let sut: TestTreeComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestTreeComponent>;
    //
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ TreeModule ],
            declarations: [ Tree, TestTreeComponent ]
        });
        //
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent( TestTreeComponent );
        sut = fixture.componentInstance;
        //
        fixture.detectChanges( ); // trigger initial data binding
        fixture.whenStable( );
    });
    /*
    ** public static treeScrollToSelectedItem( tree: Tree, elementIdName: string ): number
    */
    it( 'treeScrollToSelectedItem, nested selected ...', fakeAsync( ( ) => {
        // given
        sut.selected = sut.treeData[2].children[2].children[1];
        tick( 100 );
        fixture.detectChanges( ); // trigger initial data binding
        fixture.whenStable( );
        console.warn( sut.mtree.selection );
        // when
        const ret: number = _PCOMMON.treeScrollToSelectedItem( sut.mtree, 'myTree' );
        // then
        expect( ret ).toEqual( 7 );
    } ) );
    //
    it( 'treeScrollToSelectedItem, first nested selected ...', fakeAsync( ( ) => {
        // given
        sut.selected = sut.treeData[2].children[0];
        tick( 100 );
        fixture.detectChanges( ); // trigger initial data binding
        fixture.whenStable( );
        // when
        const ret: number = _PCOMMON.treeScrollToSelectedItem( sut.mtree, 'myTree' );
        // then
        console.warn( ret );
        expect( ret ).toEqual( 3 );
    } ) );
    //
    it( 'treeScrollToSelectedItem, root item ...', fakeAsync( ( ) => {
        // given
        sut.selected = sut.treeData[2];
        tick( 100 );
        fixture.detectChanges( ); // trigger initial data binding
        fixture.whenStable( );
        // when
        const ret: number = _PCOMMON.treeScrollToSelectedItem( sut.mtree, 'myTree' );
        // then
        expect( ret ).toEqual( 2 );
    } ) );
    //
});
```

Comment: In my Angular app I had to call it asynchronous to assure the tree DOM is created:         setTimeout(() => { this.treeScrollToSelectedItem(this.folderTree, 'folderTree') }, 1);

Comment: Hey Roman: I'm not partial to setTimeout, because it makes testing difficult.  I don't know where you placed the timeout, but I suggest a lifecycle hook of ngAfterViewInit or ngAfterContentInit.  See the Angular doc on Lifecycle Hooks (https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty straightforward way of doing this. The only difference is that I already don't use the default label on the tree, but use the ng-template.

I will post a simplified way as if I was using the default label

```
<p-tree [value]="tree">
    <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
        <div id="tree-node-key-{{node.key}}">
            {{node.label}}
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-tree>
```

After, you just expands all the parents in case they are collapsed and find the node by the id:

```
private scrollTreeNodeIntoView(searchedNode: TreeNode): void {
  // Expands all parent nodes of the searched node
  let parent = searchedNode.parent;
  while (parent !== null && parent !== undefined) {
    parent.expanded = true;
    parent = parent.parent;
  }
  
  // Finds node by id
  const obj = document.getElementById(`tree-node-key-${searchedNode.key}`);
  obj.scrollIntoView();
}
```